# Trouble manipulating jQuery element stored in variable

Tags: jquery, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I'm experiencing a strange problem.

I can set and access this variable seemingly without trouble:

```
var $element = $(this);
```

Jasmine spec:

```
it("should have a class if date has an event", function() {
    $element.events({date_override:"05/01"});
    expect($element).toHaveClass("party");
});
```

This is the code that aims to make that pass:

```
$element.addClass(events[todays_date]);
```

The test fails… even though console output shows that the element has the class.

```
console.log($element); //[h1#logo.party, selector: "#logo", context: document]
console.log($element.hasClass('party')); //true
```

When I run the code on a simple page, no Jasmine involved, the class indeed is not added to the element. It seems to see $element as undefined.

So…

1. Test fails
2. Demo fails
3. In-code checks seem to 'pass'

Why does $element seem to be undefined (in test and demo) while the console output (in the Jasmine runner) shows that the class is being added?

I'm running jQuery 2.1.3 and Jasmine 2.2.0 (with jasmine-jquery 2.0.7).

Thanks for your help.